# How Can I find my Community Wiki Question?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I was looking forward to the answers..taking notes and everything..

this is my original question:

[How to Study the Suttas?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/8462/how-to-study-the-suttas)

how would i find them on community wiki.I don't know how it works.Is it transferred to a different site? Can somebody locate this question please.

I opened this site: http://community-sitcom.wikia.com/wiki/Community_Wiki

Typed in Search Box: How to Study the Suttas?

I can't find it :-( I get random stuff like Teach me How to Understand Christmas :-(

I don't know what is happening with my question or where it's gone to..
:-( :-( :-(

Comment: It's still on OUR community... just search at Buddhism.SE and you'll find it as usual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You question and all its answers are at (i.e. continue to be found at) the same URL as before i.e. they are at [`https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/8462/254`](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/8462/254)

When a topic is "converted to community wiki" that only means that a moderator set a bitflag (i.e. a checkbox) on the question, without moving it to another location (the topic continues to be located on the stackexchange site).

It is unrelated to Wikipedia or Wikia.

Some further information about what Stackexchange calls "community wiki" can be found e.g. in this topic: [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/139866)